# R: reading a binary file that is zipped

Tags: r

I am trying to parse some online weather data with R. The data is a binary file that has been gzipped. An example file is:

`ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/precip/CPC_UNI_PRCP/GAUGE_GLB/V1.0/2005/PRCP_CU_GAUGE_V1.0GLB_0.50deg.lnx.20050101.gz`

If I download the file to my computer and manually unzip it, I can easily do the following:

```
  myFile <- ( "/tmp/PRCP_CU_GAUGE_V1.0GLB_0.50deg.lnx.20050101" )
  to.read = file( myFile, "rb")
  myPoints <- readBin(to.read, real(), n=1e6, size = 4, endian = "little")
```

What I would prefer to do is automate both the download/unzip along with the read. So I thought that would be as simple as the following:

```
p <- gzcon( url( "ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/precip/CPC_UNI_PRCP/GAUGE_GLB/V1.0/2005/PRCP_CU_GAUGE_V1.0GLB_0.50deg.lnx.20050101.gz" ) )
myPoints <- readBin(p, real(), n=1e6, size = 4, endian = "little")
```

This seems to work just dandy, but in the manual step the vector `myPoints` has length 518400, which is accurate. However if R handles the download and read as in the second example, I get a different length vector every time I run the code. Seriously. I'm not smoking anything. I swear. I run it multiple time and each time the vector is a different length, always less than the expected 518400.

I also tried getting R to download the gzip file using the following:

```
temp <- tempfile()
myFile <- download.file("ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/precip/CPC_UNI_PRCP/GAUGE_GLB/V1.0/2005/PRCP_CU_GAUGE_V1.0GLB_0.50deg.lnx.20050101.gz",temp)
```

I found that often that would return a Warning about the file not being the expected size. Like the following:

```
Warning message:
In download.file("ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/precip/CPC_UNI_PRCP/GAUGE_GLB/V1.0/2005/PRCP_CU_GAUGE_V1.0GLB_0.50deg.lnx.20050101.gz",  :
  downloaded length 162176 != reported length 179058
```

Any tips you can throw my way that might help me solve this?

-J

Comment: Just a comment for the record, but the automated version using `gzcon()` works fine for me following repeated runs; all gave the correct length.

Comment: Further testing showed that this works for me if I'm using R from the command prompt, but not from inside of RStuido. I think I found an RStudio bug.

Comment: I've reported this as a possible RStudio bug: http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/600-conflict-with-rstudio-and-reading-connections

Comment: @JD Long I've just tested your code using RStudio 0.94.48 and it worked OK

Comment: @lselzer it appears to be specific to RStudio Server running on Ubuntu.

Comment: I see this a lot, reports on "R" that turn out to be some interface to it. Oughta be a law . . .

Comment: @mdsummer, I think there is a law: Murphy's Law :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
R> remfname <- "ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/precip/CPC_UNI_PRCP/GAUGE_GLB/V1.0/2005/PRCP_CU_GAUGE_V1.0GLB_0.50deg.lnx.20050101.gz"
R> locfname <- "/tmp/data.gz"
R> download.file(remfname, locfname)
trying URL 'ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/precip/CPC_UNI_PRCP/GAUGE_GLB/V1.0/2005/PRCP_CU_GAUGE_V1.0GLB_0.50deg.lnx.20050101.gz'
ftp data connection made, file length 179058 bytes
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 174 Kb

R> con <- gzcon(file(locfname, "rb"))
R> myPoints <- readBin(con, real(), n=1e6, size = 4, endian = "little")
R> close(con)
R> str(myPoints)
 num [1:518400] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
R>
```

Comment: This is really odd. I get the same erratic behavior. It will sometimes download it all, but other times it only gets part of the file.

Comment: Other folks are telling me they have no problems. I'm going to try another machine.

Comment: I was fearing that -- smells like a web proxy that does something naughty.

Comment: I just tested this outside of RStudio and it worked :O I think I just found an RStudio bug!