# How can I download CHIRPS precipitation data in .gz format?

Tags: r, ftp, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to download CHIRPS data from ftp://ftp.chg.ucsb.edu/pub/org/chg/products/CHIRPS-2.0/africa_daily/tifs/p25/2010/. The heavyRain package is outdated and the earthEngineGrabR package (to pull data from Google's Earth Engine, https://developers.google.com/earth-engine) seems to have some bugs. Here are a few of my attempts.

```
lst.files <- list(
 list(
url2 = "ftp://chg-ftpout.geog.ucsb.edu/pub/org/chg/products/CHIRPS -2.0/africa_daily/tifs/p25/2010/chirps-v2.0.2010.01.01.tif.gz"
, target = "chirps-v2.0.2010.01.01.tif.gz"))

#download gzipped files (only if file does not exist)
lapply(lst.files, function(x)
 if(!file.exists(x$target)) download.file(x$url2, x$target))

#open files
lst <- lapply(lst.files, function(x) {
  df <- readr::read_table2(x$target)
  })
```

Here's the error message:
Error in guess_header_(datasource, tokenizer, locale) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'II*'

And here's another attempt:

```
library(RCurl)
library(foreign)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

setwd <- "C://Desktop"
url <- "ftp://chg-ftpout.geog.ucsb.edu"
years = c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019")

lapply(years, function (x){
  url <- paste(url, "/pub/org/chg/products/CHIRPS-2.0/africa_daily/tifs/p25/", x, ".gz", sep = "")
  filename <- paste("CHIRPS", x, ".gz", sep = "")
  foldername <- paste("CHIRPS", x, sep = "")
  filename

  if (file.exists(filename)==FALSE){
    download.file(url, filename)
  }

  if (file.exists(foldername)==FALSE){
    dir.create(foldername)
  }

  if(length(list.files(path = foldername, pattern="*.gz")) == 0){
    unzip(filename)
    }

  for (fl in (list.files(pattern=".gz"))){
      file.copy(fl, foldername)

    file.remove(fl)
}})
```

Here's the error message:
trying URL 'ftp://chg-ftpout.geog.ucsb.edu/pub/org/chg/products/CHIRPS-2.0/africa_daily/tifs/p25/2010.gz'
Error in download.file(url, filename) : 
  cannot open URL 'ftp://chg-ftpout.geog.ucsb.edu/pub/org/chg/products/CHIRPS-2.0/africa_daily/tifs/p25/2010.gz'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, filename) :
 Error in download.file(url, filename) : 
  cannot open URL 'ftp://chg-ftpout.geog.ucsb.edu/pub/org/chg/products/CHIRPS-2.0/africa_daily/tifs/p25/2010.gz'

And here's what happens using the example provided on the github readme file for earthEngineGrabR, https://github.com/JesJehle/earthEngineGrabR:

```
> library(earthEngineGrabR)
> library(tidyverse)
> library(sf)
> Chirps_data <- ee_grab(data = ee_data_collection(datasetID = 'UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY'
+                                          , spatialReducer = 'mean'
+                                          , temporalReducer = 'sum'
+                                          , timeStart = "2016-01-01"
+                                          , timeEnd = "2016-12-31"
+                                          , resolution = 200)
+                        , targetArea = system.file('data/territories.shp', package = 'earthEngineGrabR'))
```

Here's the output of the code where it starts, but then gets stuck:

Auto-refreshing stale OAuth token.

upload: territories is already uploaded 
Should the file be deleted and uploaded again? [Y/N]: Y
Files deleted:
  * territories: 1AOc2yzIV1DGDgfUULNA6Co1M37xcWTFLRbdKOegs
Creating Fusion Table: territories

Error: With the given product argument no valid data could be requested.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In (function (text)  : printing of extremely long output is truncated
2: Error on Earth Engine servers for data product: UCSB-CHG-CHIRPS-DAILY_s-mean_t-sum_2016-01-01to2016-12-31
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords): EEException: Unexpected HTTP error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)

Can anyone help me access either of these datasources?

Comment: Your first attempt works for me if I delete the spurious space in the middle of the URL: `.../CHIRPS -2.0/...`

Comment: Thanks @AndrewGustar. The spurious space was an posting error as I was learning how to enter a post. It doesn't work for me yet, but I'll keep at it.

Comment: I do get the error with reading the tif.gz file. I did get it to work with the solution on this question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088695/r-read-geotiff-from-gz-file-with-a-connection-and-raster-package. It throws a few warnings, but at least `image(lst[[1]])` gives a sideways outline of Africa!

Comment: Here is another approach that might be worth investigating... https://climateserv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: Hi @AndrewGustar, I posted a solution and link to the YouTube video where I found the solution. Thanks for your help, it encouraged me to keep digging in my spare time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this by adapting the code from this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBfx1L16qlM. Using the code below, I can download all the files for a given year, and then I just repeat the code for the next year manually by adapting the url. It's not an elegant solution, but it works.

```
library(RCurl)
setwd("working directory file name")
url <- "ftp://chg-ftpout.geog.ucsb.edu/pub/org/chg/products/CHIRPS-2.0/africa_daily/tifs/p25/2010/" 
filenames <- getURL(url, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE)
filenames <- strsplit(filenames, "\r\n")
filenames = unlist(filenames)
filenames

for (filename in filenames) {
  download.file(paste(url, filename, sep = ""), paste(getwd(), "/", filename, sep = ""))
}
```

This downloads all the .gz files to my working directory. Faster solutions are welcome, but this does work.