# Decompress .tif.gz file using R

Tags: r, gzip, tiff

I got data from Chirps in tif.gz format, I tried `R.utils::gunzip` to get the maps but I got an error.

```
file<-"./chirps-v2.0.1981.01.01.tif.gz"
R.utils::gunzip(file,remove=F)
```

Error:

```
Error in readBin(inn, what = raw(0L), size = 1L, n = BFR.SIZE) : 
  error reading from the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readBin(inn, what = raw(0L), size = 1L, n = BFR.SIZE) :
  invalid or incomplete compressed data
```

[data link](https://data.chc.ucsb.edu/products/CHIRPS-2.0/global_daily/tifs/p05/1981/chirps-v2.0.1981.01.01.tif.gz).

If there is a better alternative to unzip these files it will be a great solution. Thank you in advance.

I tried these but it didn't work
[R: read GeoTiff from gz file with a connection and raster package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088695/r-read-geotiff-from-gz-file-with-a-connection-and-raster-package)
[Decompress gz file using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764499/decompress-gz-file-using-r)

Comment: This suggests that the file is corrupted. I would download it again, making sure you are not getting a cached version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me:

```r
url <- paste0("https://data.chc.ucsb.edu/products/CHIRPS-2.0/",
              "global_daily/tifs/p05/1981/chirps-v2.0.1981.01.01.tif.gz")
download.file(url, "chirps-v2.0.1981.01.01.tif.gz")
R.utils::gunzip("chirps-v2.0.1981.01.01.tif.gz", remove = FALSE)
```

**File: chirps-v2.0.1981.01.01.tif**

[image]