# vroom id argument - use filenames instead of archive name

Tags: r, vroom

I'd like to read a remote archive file with vroom and get a additional column with the filenames instead of archive name. Is this possible with vroom without the local archive_extract step as shown in the example below?

Thank you

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(archive)
library(vroom)

file <-  "ftp://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/daily/regnie/ra2021m.tar"

test1 <- vroom_fwf(file,  col_positions = fwf_widths(rep(4, 611)),
            col_types = , cols(.default = col_integer()),
          na = "-999", id = "filename")

test1$filename %>% unique()
#> [1] "ftp://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/daily/regnie/ra2021m.tar"

my_dir <- fs::file_temp() %>% fs::dir_create()

archive_extract(file, dir = my_dir)

test2 <- fs::dir_ls(my_dir)  %>%
  vroom_fwf(  col_positions = fwf_widths(rep(4, 611)),
              col_types = , cols(.default = col_integer()),
              na = "-999", id = "filename") 

test2$filename %>% unique()
#>   [1] ".../AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp2TTpuI/filebfd82b6b1f6/ra210101.gz"
#>   [2] ".../AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp2TTpuI/filebfd82b6b1f6/ra210102.gz"
#>   [3] ".../AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp2TTpuI/filebfd82b6b1f6/ra210103.gz"
...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the [vroom vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vroom/vignettes/vroom.html) suggests:

> **Reading single files from multiple multi-file zip archives**
>
> If you are reading a zip file that contains multiple files with the
> same format, you can use a wrapper function like this:
>
> ```
> read_all_zip <- function(file, ...) {
>   filenames <- unzip(file, list = TRUE)$Name
>   vroom(purrr::map(filenames, ~ unz(file, .x)), ...)
> }
> ```

Adapted to your use case, this gives something like:

```
read_all_tar_remote_v1 <- function(file) {
  con <- file(file, open = "rb")
  filenames <- untar(con, list = T)
  df <- purrr::map(filenames,~ vroom_fwf(archive_read(file, file = .x, format='tar'),
                                 col_positions = fwf_widths(rep(4, 611)),
                                 col_types = , cols(.default = col_integer()),
                                 na = "-999", id = "filename", guess_max=2000))
  df
}
read_all_tar_remote_v1(file)
```

However, this is slow (and crashes more often than not with my poor internet connection) because, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59954089/5224236), `untar` needs to read the whole archive in order to get the file names.

> this **does** download the whole archive, since untar needs to read the whole file to see what's in it. There is no master directory in a tar file for untar to read; each file always has its own 512-byte header block. You don't need to save it to your hard disk to read the directory, but it may be just as easy to do so.

Hence, I suppose, your question.

One way to avoid this is to use `archive_read` with an index position.

```
read_all_tar_remote_v2 <- function(file) {
  df <- purrr::map(1:365,~ vroom_fwf(archive_read(file, file = .x, format='tar'),
                  col_positions = fwf_widths(rep(4, 611)),
                  col_types = , cols(.default = col_integer()),
                  na = "-999", id = "filename", guess_max=2000))
df
}
```

This does not give you the exact file names however, but at least an index which allows you to differentiate them. This is the only improvement over your current implementation.

```
mylist <- read_all_tar_remote_v2(file)
mylist[[1]]$filename %>% unique
[1] "archive_read(ftp://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/daily/regnie/ra2021m.tar)[1]"
```

Since you might not know the number of files prior to reading, you may want to include error management in your function.

```
read_all_tar_remote_v3 <- function(file, maxfiles = 10000) {
  mylist <- list()
  for (i in 1:maxfiles) {
    print(paste('reading file', i,'/', maxfiles))
   #ERROR HANDLING
   possibleError <- tryCatch({
     mydf <- vroom_fwf(archive_read(file, file = i, format='tar'),
                                           col_positions = fwf_widths(rep(4, 611)),
                                           col_types = , cols(.default = col_integer()),
                                           na = "-999", id = "filename", guess_max=2000)
     mylist[[i]] <- mydf
     },
     error=function(e) e
   )
   
   if(inherits(possibleError, "error")){
     break
   } 
  }
   return(mylist)
}
```

Is this faster or better than your current approach? I let you decide, but I wouldn't say so.

I would keep extracting the individual files, as reading names without the whole thing unfortunately seems to be a limitation of the `tar` format.