Keep file names merging list with lapply?
I am importing several .csv files of temperature registers from a folder, and need to create a single table mergind them all, in which the first 15 lines must be skipped and the file names must be kept.
How to keep the file names?
Any advice is appreciated
Thanks
> setwd("")
> 
> files <- list.files("folder",pattern = ".csv", recursive
> = T, full.names = T)
> 
> data<- do.call(rbind, lapply
>                 (files, read.csv, as.is=T, skip = 15, header = TRUE))

With this code I get the table but do not know how to add a new variable with the file names
> data
                   time temp
1   2019-11-29 19:39:28 14.4
2   2019-11-29 20:09:28 14.4
3   2019-11-29 20:39:28 14.5
4   2019-11-29 21:09:28 14.5


purrr::map_dfr() supports this out of the box. If you want to stay with base R, you need to change your function application to add the filename as a new column inside the lapply.

And it should be pattern = "\\.csv$" (i.e., match literal dot and only at end of strings).

Your approch assumes that all files share a common number of columns with the exact same names.

I guess @KonradRudolph is referring to purrr::map_dfr(files, read.csv, as.is = TRUE, header = TRUE, .id = "source"). I suspect as.is might be not properly used, have not checked.

readr::read_*() / vroom::vroom() can take a vector of file names and return a single frame with id column with file paths.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73109313/vroom-id-argument-use-filenames-instead-of-archive-name and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67862678/assigning-id-values-from-values-not-names-with-purrrmap-dfr

You might want something along the lines
files = list.files("folder", pattern = "\\.csv$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
# data0 = 
lapply(files, \(i) { # or basename(files)?
  read.csv(i, as.is = TRUE, skip = 15L, header = TRUE) |>
    transform(name = i) # or sub(".csv", "", i) instead of i
  }) |> do.call(what = "rbind") 

Edit:
Based on your comment I suggest
# data0 = 
lapply(basename(files), \(i) { # or files
  read.csv(i, skip = 15L) |>
    transform(source = sub(".csv", "", i)) # basename here?
  }) |> do.call(what = "rbind") 


It works nice, but I would like to drop the folder from the name variable and only have each files name. Is there a way to do so?

Have you tried transform(name = sub(".csv", "", basename(i)))?

If we use Map rather than lapply then the row names will contain the file paths followed by a sequence number.  Add whatever args you need to read.csv below but note that header=TRUE is the default so it is not needed and as.is=TRUE may not be needed either. No packages are used.
do.call("rbind", Map(\(x) read.csv(x), files))

For example, if we generate the test files as shown in the Note at the end then
files <- Sys.glob("folder/*.csv")
do.call("rbind", Map(read.csv, files))
##                X Time demand
## folder/a.csv.1 1    1    8.3
## folder/a.csv.2 2    2   10.3
## folder/b.csv.1 3    3   19.0
## folder/b.csv.2 4    4   16.0
## folder/c.csv.1 5    5   15.6
## folder/c.csv.2 6    7   19.8

Added
In a comment it was later mentioned that a column containing only the filename without folder or extension is desired.  In that case it is easier to do it like this.  Note that tools comes with R and so does not have to be installed.
library(tools)

Read <- \(x) cbind(read.csv(x), file = file_path_sans_ext(basename(x)))
do.call("rbind", lapply(files, Read))
##   X Time demand file
## 1 1    1    8.3    a
## 2 2    2   10.3    a
## 3 3    3   19.0    b
## 4 4    4   16.0    b
## 5 5    5   15.6    c
## 6 6    7   19.8    c

Note
dir.create("folder")
s <- split(BOD, rep(letters[1:3], each = 2))
junk <- Map(write.csv, s, paste0(file.path("folder", names(s)), ".csv"))

