Loading multiple csv files creating new variable with file name in R
I need to load multiple csv files into R, combine them into one dataframe or tibble, and create a new column based on a portion of the original file name. I have been able to accomplish this by creating intermediate objects, as demonstrated in the code below, but I have many more to do and would like to run it all in one piped chain or for loop without creating these intermediate objects. (I have used skip = 4 because the data do not begin until the 5th row in the original csv file.)
# load multiple accelerometer files for one animal and combine into one file for the individual collar first

# accel_1305

list_1305 <- list.files("data/Accel2024/1305",
                        pattern = ".csv",
                        full.names = T)

accel_1305 <- map_dfr(list_1305, ~
                        read_csv(.x, skip = 4))

# accel_1306

list_1306 <- list.files("data/Accel2024/1306",
                        pattern = ".csv",
                        full.names = T)

accel_1306 <- map_dfr(list_1306, ~
                        read_csv(.x, skip = 4))

# combine all individual collar accelerometer files and create collar id variable from dataframe name

accel_data <-
  bind_rows('1305' = accel_1305,
            '1306' = accel_1306,
            .id = 'collar_id')

the final output should be structured like this

data.frame(collar_id = c(1305, 1306),
           time = c(0615, 0819),
           x = c(31, 16),
           y = c(-5, 6),
           z = c(6, 5))


There are several good answer on SO regarding this topic. You do not really need {purrr} for this, although the map_*-function has a conveninent argument to set an "file-origin id" directly. Please use TRUE instead of T. It seems like the arguments of list.files need to be specified more carefully. Where exactly arise your problem. Your question is very likely a duplicate. I will post some related discussions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190280/whats-wrong-with-my-function-to-load-multiple-csv-files-into-single-dataframe or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819433/reading-multiple-csv-files-from-a-folder-into-a-single-dataframe-in-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79073542/keep-file-names-merging-list-with-lapply/79073701#79073701 and several more (see links on top of last link ; question closed)
